# PHP Tables 3X2 .. 3 Rows, Infinite Columns

Tags: php, html

i have a database and a table name 'products'.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db="webdevproject";
```

My question is i want to display this table by 3 Rows , N Columns(Unkknown N). For Example

I have table name products and i want to display its content just like illustrated below

```
|Product Image|         |Product Image|      |Product Image|
|Product Name |         |Product Name |      |Product Name |
|Description|           |Description|        |Description  |
|Price|                 |Price|              |Price        |
```

And whenever i added new one columns to the database. It will display similar below

```
|Product Image|         |Product Image|      |Product Image|
|Product Name |         |Product Name |      |Product Name |
|Description|           |Description|        |Description  |
|Price|                 |Price|              |Price        |

|Product Image|
|Product Name |
|Description  |
|Price        |
```

The limit is 3 Rows , infinite Columns as long it exist in the DB.
I will be using this to display information to the webpage.
The Question is , How do i code this? Im on the Level dump programmer and my logic skill are not much

Comment: Ideally you would not try to make this an HTML `table` to begin with (that doesn't make too much sense structurally/semantically here, I think), but output several elements containing all the data for one product each, and then _format_ the result using CSS, so that those elements show next to each other.

Comment: If you don't want to do that, but actually create a `table` - then the keyword here would be "pivot." That can be done in SQL, so that you would directly get the data in a form you could just loop over to create your table output, but that is rather complex. You can also do it in PHP, in that case you should put all your data into an array first, then you can count the items and write loops that access the necessary elements to output in a certain position, via index.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table  style="width:1000px">
      
     <?php
    
    
    $records = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from products"); // fetch data from database
                   
                        
$x=0;
   while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        { 
         //Start of the While Loop
             ?>
    
                                
            <td style="width:200px">
            <div id="FirstProduct">
            <img src="../Product Image/<?php echo $data['Product_Image']; ?>"width="200" height="194">
           <div id="ProductName"><h5><?php echo $data['Product_Name']; ?></h5></div>
           <div class="Price">P <?php echo number_format($data['Price']); ?></div> 
           <div class="Ads"><?php echo $data['Product_Description']; ?></div>
           <div class="Size_Available"><b>Product Size :</b><?php echo $data['Product_Size']; ?></div>  
           <div class="Quantity_Available"><b>Quantity Available : </b><?php echo $data['Quantity']; ?><div>
             <br>
       
            <label for="Quantity">Quantity :</label>
            <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="<?php echo $data['Quantity']; ?>" value="">                                   
            <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>  
            </div>
            </td>
                                    
            <?php
                 $x=$x+1;
                 if($x==3){
            ?>
                        </tr><tr>
                        <?php 
                        $x=0;  
                          } 
              ?>    
                            <?php    
                            // End of the While Loop
                            }
                            ?>
                                    </table>
```

*The If statement is used for limiting number of rows